# Setting First Column Spanned to align child treeview with parent row takes long time and freezes main thread

Tags: c++, qt5

In my Qt project, I've created a custom tree view. Another custom treeview is the child of each row in that treeview. I'm using "setFirstColumnSpanned" to align the child treeview with the parent row's viewport, however doing so for a huge dataset takes a long time and causes the main thread to freeze.

This is the driver code:

```
childtv = new CustomTreeviewClass();
childtv->SetParentIndex(parentIndex);
QStandardItemModel *Model = new QStandardItemModel();
childtv->setModel(Model);
QStandardItem *childItem = new QStandardItem;
ui->treevRadar->AddTreeView(ParentItem,ui->treevRadar,childItem,childtv);
```

This is where I add new TreeView:

```
void CustomTreeviewClass::AddTreeView(QStandardItem *parentItem, QTreeView *ParentTv, QStandardItem *childItem, QTreeView *ChildTv) {

    const int WidgetRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;
    parentItem->setChild(0, childItem);
    childItem->setData(QVariant::fromValue(static_cast<void*>(ChildTv)), WidgetRole);
    ParentTv->setIndexWidget(childItem->index(), ChildTv);
    ParentTv->setFirstColumnSpanned(childItem->index().row(), parentItem->index(), true);
}
```

I tried commenting the following line:

`ParentTv->setFirstColumnSpanned(childItem->index().row(), parentItem->index(), true);`

And then doing the following in a slot invoked by triggering `expanded` signal of QTreeView:

```
void WindowClass::OnExpand(const QModelIndex &index) {

    if(index.isValid()) {
        QStandardItemModel *model = (QStandardItemModel *)index.model();
        QStandardItem *item = model->item(index.row(), 1);
        if(mmap_Child .contains(item->text().toLongLong())) {
            ui->treevRadar->setFirstColumnSpanned(mmap_Child.value(item->text().toLongLong())->index().row(),
                                                  mmap_Child.value(item->text().toLongLong())->parent()->index(),
                                                  true);
        }
    }
}
```

The `mmap_Child` is a private member map that keeps track of the child tree views for all the rows.
This kinda works but I'll have to do the same in every other window that I use the custom treeview in.

Is there a better solution to this?